# Locate email on exchange server that has "/" in the name using C# and WebDAV

Tags: c#, email, escaping, exchange-server, webdav

I asked and answered a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008847/read-subject-and-body-of-email-using-webdav-and-c) that is related to this issue and shows how I'm accessing my emails using C# and WebDAV.  This code works fine for everything except emails that have a forward slash in the subject.

Example email subject:

"You have a new/changed record to review.eml"

Example Exchange URI:

"http://MyExchangeServerName/Exchange/MyName@Test.com/Inbox/"

The full path to this email would be:

"http://MyExchangeServerName/Exchange/MyName@Test.com/Inbox/You have a new/changed record to review.eml"

Unfortunately, this path isn't looking for the "You have a new/changed record to review.eml" email in my Inbox, it is looking for an email titled "changed record to review.eml" in the "You have a new" folder of my Inbox (which, of course, does not exist).

Is there a way to construct this string so that the forward slash of the email is recognized as being part of the true email name, rather than a subfolder of my inbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URL encode the subject line so that it is a valid URL.  Each "/" would be replaced by its encoding "%2F".

For example, "http://MyExchangeServerName/Exchange/MyName@Test.com/Inbox/You have a new%2Fchanged record to review.eml"

Comment: For some reason, replacing the "/" with "%2F" didn't work, but changing it to "_xF8FF_" did.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!